# ERROR: Could not find method armeabi-v7a() for arguments [arm64-v8a]

Tags: android, android-studio, 32bit-64bit

I tried to change my application to support 32-bit and 64-bit, but when i change the **build.gradle** like this.

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "id.co.poslogistics.agendakegiatan"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    ndk.abiFilters = 'armeabi-v7a' 'arm64-v8a' 'x86' 'x86_64'
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

but when i gradle it, the error will show like this

**ERROR:**

> Could not find method armeabi-v7a() for arguments [arm64-v8a] on DefaultConfig_Decorated{name=main, dimension=null, minSdkVersion=DefaultApiVersion{mApiLevel=15, mCodename='null'}, targetSdkVersion=DefaultApiVersion{mApiLevel=28, mCodename='null'}, renderscriptTargetApi=null, renderscriptSupportModeEnabled=null, renderscriptSupportModeBlasEnabled=null, renderscriptNdkModeEnabled=null, versionCode=1, versionName=1.0, applicationId=id.co.poslogistics.agendakegiatan, testApplicationId=null, testInstrumentationRunner=null, testInstrumentationRunnerArguments={}, testHandleProfiling=null, testFunctionalTest=null, signingConfig=null, resConfig=null, mBuildConfigFields={}, mResValues={}, mProguardFiles=[], mConsumerProguardFiles=[], mManifestPlaceholders={}, mWearAppUnbundled=null} of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.DefaultConfig.

can anyone help me. thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Your config**

```
ndk.abiFilters = 'armeabi-v7a' 'arm64-v8a' 'x86' 'x86_64'
```

**should be**

```
ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'
```

**or**

```
ndk {
    abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86' ,'x86_64'
}
```

Comment: Good answer.  Looks like the documentation on the Android Developers site is wrong https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit, but they don't have a feedback button on that page to let them know.

Comment: Working solution, Thanks