# Integrate 64-bit compatibility to 32-bit android apk due to recent announcement from Google Play

Tags: android, 32bit-64bit

I want to add 64 bit compatibility to my current android app currently 32 bit using android studio. I already go through the https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit#building_with_android_studio_or_gradle.

i need to change code in `build gradle` file but when i build the app and suppose to have `arm64-v8a` and/or `x86_64` but don't have.

Can someone clarify to me how the exact steps?

[cordova plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6z1h.png)

[.so file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gJ5e.png)

Here is screenshot of my plugin and .so file of my app
i am using ionic 1 and build app from android studio

build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.app'

    android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
       appId "com.google.example.64bit"
       minSdkVersion 15
       targetSdkVersion 28
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"
       ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
      // ...reference

     productFlavors {
            armeabi {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 1
                ndk {
                    abiFilters = ["armeabi"]
                }
            }
            armv7 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 2
                ndk {
                    abiFilters = ["armeabi-v7a"]
                }
            }
            arm64 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 3
                ndk {
                    abiFilters = ["arm64-v8a"]
                }
            }
            x86 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 4
                ndk {
                    abiFilters = ["x86"]
                }
            }
            x86_64 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 5
                ndk {
                    abiFilters = ["x86_64"]
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I was under the impression that Ionic v1 uses Cordova which in turn uses the Android framework's available WebView. Unless you have native code (C/C++) the 64 bit requirement does not affect you. If you do see: [How to make Android apps which support both 32-bit and 64-bit architecture?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48549563/295004)

Comment: i done some reading and from what i understand i need this arm64-v8a and/or x86_64 to make my apps support 64 bit. Correct me if im wrong

Comment: To be clear you have followed: https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit#does_your_app_include_64-bit_libraries and found 32 bit folders. If you found no folders/files, you are fine, you have no 32-bit native (C/C++) code libraries which will need 64-bit versions.

Comment: i already follow the step to check using apl analyzer and found armeabi-v7a and x86 folder inside the lib

Comment: As you are building an Ionic v1 app, you should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56334489/edit) your question to include what '.so' files you found along with what plug-ins/additions were used (camera filter?). If you don't have the source code for the libraries, you are dependent on those other library owners to provide 64-bit native libraries.

Comment: you mean i need to list down all the plugin i used and also what .so file i have in my "lib" folder ? How can i know the plugin i use can support 64-bit. so

Comment: Only you (should) know what your app does. I ask you to list both as others may be more familiar with the native library. It would also help to describe the function of your app which would require a 32-bit & 64-bit C/C++ library.

Comment: okay i understand now. I will make amend my question. Thanks for clarification