# Google play : This release is not compliant with the Google play 64-bit requirement

Tags: android, google-play, shared-libraries, android-native-library

I build an android app which uses a 32- bit Native library "library.so" which I don't have its source code 
The app is working well for both 32-bit and 64-bit but the problem that I can't upload the app on Google play it shows the following error:

[image: Google play error]

So I tried to add arm64 support in the app.. And copied the 32 version of library to **armv8-a** directory. bit when I load the library it shows:

> library.so is 32-bit instead of 64-bit

Is there any solution to upload the app on google play or convert the library to 64-bit or even to get the source of library.so so I can optimize it for 64-bit

Comment: Check this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48549563/how-to-make-android-apps-which-support-both-32-bit-and-64-bit-architecture

Comment: @Kabir The answer didn't help me as I already optimized all the library for 64bit except one I need to force load it from 32bit

Answer (score 1):

Copying the 32 version library to armv64-v8a won't work. Googleplay would check the so validity.