# While trying to upload an apk to google play console i get an error and warning message

Tags: android, google-play-console

Error while trying to upload a apk file

Tried changing version code

Error Message
This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement

The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code: 6.

Include 64-bit and 32-bit native code in your app. Use the Android App Bundle publishing format to automatically ensure that each device architecture receives only the native code it needs. This avoids increasing the overall size of your app

Warning Message
Unoptimized APK
Warning:

This APK results in unused code and resources being sent to users. Your app could be smaller if you used the Android App Bundle. By not optimizing your app for device configurations, your app is larger to download and install on users' devices than it needs to be. Larger apps see lower install success rates and take up storage on users' devices.

Resolution:

Use the Android App Bundle to automatically optimize for device configurations, or manage it yourself with multiple APKs.

Help me upload the apk

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Android apps which support both 32-bit and 64-bit architecture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48549563/how-to-make-android-apps-which-support-both-32-bit-and-64-bit-architecture)

Comment: add following line app level build.gradle defaultConfig

ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'

Answer (score 0):

Your app relies on native libraries, either code you compiled or from external dependencies. From the error message, it looks like you are providing only native libraries in 32-bit (e.g. armeabi-v7a, x86) and it is now required to also provide native libraries in 64-bit (e.g. arm64-v8a, x86_64).
Make sure you compile for the 64-bit ABIs, or depend on libraries that support 64-bit.