# Google play :Apk Upload error becauseof 64-bit requirement

Tags: android, google-play

I excluded all the so files from my app, but still I cannot rollout it in the Googleplay.
[image]

I extracted my app, there is no lib directory, which would contain so files.

[image]

I'm just confused about the 64-bit requirement. Could anyone explain the rule of googleplay policy? The user experience is really not so well.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit

Comment: I think there is no native code in this apk

Comment: Go through this also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48549563/how-to-make-android-apps-which-support-both-32-bit-and-64-bit-architecture

Comment: "If you have no native (NDK) code, that is you only write Java/Dex code, then you don't need to do anything". I don't have native code, but still there exists the issue

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/6296561

Answer (score -1):

For fixing this issue, you should do these things:

1- Disable x86 build in Other Settings,(you won't lost much users!)

2- Enable Custom Gradle Template and change abiFilters like this in `Assets\Plugins\Android\mainTemplate.gradle`:

```
ndk {
        abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'
    }
```

3- Build an apk and release your application without any headache.

After spending 2 weeks on other similar approaches for fixing this problem, finally I found this solution and it works like a charm.

Comment: No, Don't get me wrong, in Unity3d build options you can see 3 kind of architecture for build: 1-x86, 2-armv7 and 3-arm64. armv7 is 32 bit and if you disable just x86, you won't lost 32bit users(98%)!. So in this case you can support both of 32 and 64 bit CPUs