# How to Include 64-bit and 32-bit native code in my app

Tags: android, 64-bit, google-play-console, android-architecture

I can't uplaod my app to playstore got this error
I have also build "Android App Bundle" to upload the app but again got this error.

This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement
The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code: 111.

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.iqvis.com.buenosdias"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 111
        versionName "10.11"
        multiDexEnabled true
        ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
```

Comment: did you try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54474417/3678308 ?

Comment: ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64' after I put this ndk filter to gradle and then I analyze apk I only see two folders armeabi-v7a and x86 only how can I include the arm64-v8a and x86_64

Answer (score 1):

In 2017, Google announced that in Aug'19 Apps on the PlayStore should provide the subsequent version of 32 bit native libraries in 64 bit. 64 bit is supported since Android 5( Lollipop ) days.

***Now to check your apk***

- Open Android Studio, and open any project.
- From the menu, select **Build > Analyze** APK and select the APK which you want to evaluate.

Now, if in the analyzer you look into lib folder, and in that you see any **.so** then you have 32-bit libraries or if you have any armeabi-v7a or x86, then you have 32-bit libraries
If you see no **.so** files, then your app requires no upgrade versions.

***Upgrade to 64 bit architecture***

```
    // Your app's build.gradle
apply plugin: 'com.android.app'

android {
   compileSdkVersion 27
   defaultConfig {
       appId "com.google.example.64bit"
       minSdkVersion 15
       targetSdkVersion 28
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"
       ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
   }
}
```

For more info check this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E96vmWkUdgA