# PlayStore -The following APKs or app bundles are available on 64-bit devices, but have only native 32-bit code: 1

Tags: android, architecture, google-play, 64-bit

I am updating  one of our native Android apps  and when I upload the apk( or bundle to play store i get the following message 
[image: GooglePlay error message]

i'am not using any native 3rd party library , also my apk  dos not contain a lib folder

[image]

Here's my  `buid.gradle` for reference

```
  buildscript {
 ...

    }



    android {
        compileSdkVersion 29
        buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "xx.xxx.xxxxx"
            minSdkVersion 19
            targetSdkVersion 29
            versionCode 9
            versionName '1.3'
            multiDexEnabled true

        }



    dependencies {
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:19.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
        implementation 'com.edwardvanraak:MaterialBarcodeScanner:0.0.6-ALPHA'


        compile('it.sephiroth.android.library.horizontallistview:hlistview:1.2.2') {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        }
        implementation 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
        implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
        // Google Play Services
        compile('com.github.johnkil.android-robototextview:robototextview:4.0.0') {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'

        }
        compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
            transitive = true
        }


        apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

    }
```

Comment: Analyse your apk file (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/apk-analyzer). It will help you to find the library causing the issue.

Comment: this is because you have to provide support for 64-bit devices. Some of your third party library which you added in your project not providing support for 64-bit devices or try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/57712641/6021469

Comment: @ShwetaChauhan already did , did not find  a lib folder  at all

Comment: is there abiFilters in your build file?

Comment: @FaridForootan  no there's not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was not caused by any native dependency as my project did not have one.I resolved the issue by disabling older builds on  GooglePlay which only supported 32bits architecture.