# Playstore Upload error : Google Play 64-bit requirement

Tags: android

I am facing this on uploading release on play store with a jar file.

This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement

The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code: 1.

Include 64-bit and 32-bit native code in your app. Use the Android App Bundle publishing format to automatically ensure that each device architecture receives only the native code that it needs. This avoids increasing the overall size of your app. Learn More

Comment: `This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48549563/how-to-make-android-apps-which-support-both-32-bit-and-64-bit-architecture